# Excel to check date in clipboard before proceeding

Tags: excel, vba, date, clipboard, error-checking

I am trying to come up with a code that will check the users clipboard to ensure that the first value in the clipboard is a date. If not then exit the sub before proceeding. The problem I am having is that this will not be a specific date- but any date. I am using this as an error checker before someone pastes data to make sure it doesnt cause other issues.

Here is the part of the code

```
    Dim MyText As String
    Dim datevalue As String
    Set MyData = New DataObject
    MyData.GetFromClipboard
    MyDate = MyData.Getdate
    

    If Left(MyText, 2) <> datevalue(date_string) Then Exit Sub

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1") = MyText
```

When its ran excel says "Compile Error: Expected Array". I assume this is because it is expecting an actual date in in the datevalue(date_string) but I cant figure out how to say "Any Date" as opposed to a specific one? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's `MyDate = MyData.Getdate`? Why are you using `Left`... how is two characters a date? Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: One issue is you have declared `datevalue As String` which overrides the built-in DateValue function.  It's the latter you are trying to use with `datevalue(date_string)`.

Comment: Another issue is `GetDate` is not a method of DataObject.